# ASP.NET image resizing with different DPI

Tags: asp.net, wpf, vb.net, image-resizing, dpi

I'm resizing images on my own server that come from a remote server. This works perfectly, but for some images it resizes it completely wrong.

This image works perfectly: 
http://www.topwedding.com/bigimage/Wedding%20Dresses/HSTSKN510/Strapless-Mermaid-Appliqued-Wedding-Dress-with-Ruched-Bodice-and-Pick-Up-Skirt.jpg

But for example this image, works terribly and ends up being really small:
http://www.topwedding.com/bigimage/Wedding%20Dresses/HS01116007/Floral-One-Shoulder-Organza-over-Satin-A-Line-Bridal-Gown-with-Pick-Ups.jpg

Upon inspection it turns out the first image has a 72 Pixels/inch and the second image has 951 Pixels/Inch.

Bad resizing was the same issue I had before (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35191841/wpf-image-resizing-and-storing-works-on-most-images-but-fails-to-resize-or-save))

But I thought that was now solved by using the `PixelWidth` and `PixelHeight` properties in my code, as suggested in the other post.

The goal is to have thumbnails that are 200 pixels wide that can be shown on a product overview page. How can I make sure the images end up being the same size?

The full code is below:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    ResizeAndSaveFast(200, 200, "http://www.topwedding.com/bigimage/Wedding%20Dresses/HSTSKN510/Strapless-Mermaid-Appliqued-Wedding-Dress-with-Ruched-Bodice-and-Pick-Up-Skirt.jpg", Server.MapPath("images\") + "1.png")
    ResizeAndSaveFast(200, 200, "http://www.topwedding.com/bigimage/Wedding%20Dresses/HS01116007/Floral-One-Shoulder-Organza-over-Satin-A-Line-Bridal-Gown-with-Pick-Ups.jpg", Server.MapPath("images\") + "2.png")
End Sub



Private Function ResizeAndSaveFast(ByVal maxWidth As Integer, ByVal maxHeight As Integer, ByVal imageURL As String, ByVal saveToPath As String) As Boolean
    Dim imgRequest As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create(imageURL)
    Dim imgResponse As WebResponse
    imgResponse = imgRequest.GetResponse()

    Dim streamPhoto As Stream = imgResponse.GetResponseStream()
    Dim memStream As New MemoryStream
    streamPhoto.CopyTo(memStream)
    memStream.Position = 0

    Dim bfPhoto As BitmapFrame = ReadBitmapFrame(memStream)

    Dim newWidth, newHeight As Integer
    Dim scaleFactor As Double

    newWidth = bfPhoto.PixelWidth
    newHeight = bfPhoto.PixelHeight
    If bfPhoto.PixelWidth > maxWidth Or bfPhoto.PixelHeight > maxHeight Then
        If bfPhoto.PixelWidth > maxWidth Then
            scaleFactor = maxWidth / bfPhoto.PixelWidth
            newWidth = Math.Round(bfPhoto.Width * scaleFactor, 0)
            newHeight = Math.Round(bfPhoto.Height * scaleFactor, 0)
        End If
        If newHeight > maxHeight Then
            scaleFactor = maxHeight / newHeight
            newWidth = Math.Round(newWidth * scaleFactor, 0)
            newHeight = Math.Round(newHeight * scaleFactor, 0)
        End If
    End If

    Dim bfResize As BitmapFrame = FastResize(bfPhoto, newWidth, newHeight)

    If bfResize Is Nothing Then Return False

    Dim baResize As Byte() = ToByteArray(bfResize)
    File.WriteAllBytes(saveToPath, baResize)
    Return True

End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code still uses `bfPhoto.Width` and `bfPhoto.Height` in its calculation (for the "width" scale factor). You can try the following code which uses only `bfPhoto.PixelWidth` and `bfPhoto.PixelHeight`, and also makes sure that the thumbnail size does not exceed the maximum width and height specified:

```
Private Function ResizeAndSaveFast(ByVal maxWidth As Integer, ByVal maxHeight As Integer, ByVal imageURL As String, ByVal saveToPath As String) As Boolean

    ...

    Dim bfPhoto As BitmapFrame = ReadBitmapFrame(memStream)

    Dim scaleFactorWidth As Double = Math.Min(1.0, maxWidth / bfPhoto.PixelWidth)
    Dim scaleFactorHeight As Double = Math.Min(1.0, maxHeight / bfPhoto.PixelHeight)
    Dim scaleFactor As Double = Math.Min(scaleFactorWidth, scaleFactorHeight)
    Dim newWidth As Integer = Math.Round(bfPhoto.PixelWidth * scaleFactor, 0)
    Dim newHeight As Integer = Math.Round(bfPhoto.PixelHeight * scaleFactor, 0)

    Dim bfResize As BitmapFrame = FastResize(bfPhoto, newWidth, newHeight)

    ...

End Function
```

Comment: Arghh...sometimes after looking at code for ages you just miss stuff like this...thanks!